# Unable to validate upload to appstore

Tags: ios, xcode, codesign, code-signing-certificate

I keep getting this message when trying to upload an app to the app store:

> Unable to validate your application. the path...
>   '/var/.../T/xcodedistpipeline.u4Q/packages/unity-iphone.ipa' does not
>   contain a file.

One of the log files says:

```
2016-05-19 13:34:43 +0000 [MT] Presenting: Error Domain=IDEFoundationErrorDomain Code=1 "Codesign failed" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Codesign failed}
```

Thanks.